# Showing $\int_0^\infty v(a)^{1-\frac\lambda{n}}\int_{a^{p/r}}^\infty w(b)\,db\,da=\int_0^\infty w(s)\int_0^{s^{r/p}}v(t)^{1-\frac\lambda{n}}\,dt\,ds$

Tags: integration, analysis

In a proof that I'm trying to understand, the following exercise is given:

> Show that $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} v(a)^{1-\frac{\lambda}{n}}\int_{a^\frac{p}{r}}^{\infty}w(b)\, db\,da \,=\, \int_{0}^{\infty}w(s)\int_{0}^{s^\frac{r}{p}}v(t)^{1-\frac{\lambda}{n}}\,dt\,ds$$
> where $0 < \lambda < n $ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. $v(a)$ and $w(b)$ are positive functions.

I was trying to solve this with a substitution but was not successful.

I'm thankful for every help!

Comment: I think it should be $s^{r/p}$, not $s^{p/r}$.

Comment: Thats correct, thank you. I edited it.

Comment: What happens when you start with the left side and interchange the order of integration?  Calculus texts should have explanations of this process.